# Connecting to an Oracle Database in R to run SQL Query

Tags: r, database, oracle, package

I am trying to connect to an Oracle Database in R. In Python, I simply use the `cx_Oracle` package, and can easily connect and run a query using the following code:

```
my_dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("host",port,sid="sid")
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user="user", password="password", dsn=my_dsn)
cursor = connection.cursor()

querystring = "SQL query"
cursor.execute(querystring)
```

Is there an equivalent package in R to use? If so, what is it, and how do I set up my bearings to connect to the Oracle database and run a query--saving the result into a data.frame? I need to be able to construct a DSN, as I have done in the code above, too. Thank you!

Comment: This question is unfortunately specifically [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), so likely to be closed. A quick search found entries for `ROracle` on both [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/index.html) and [Oracle's website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/r/roracle/overview/index.html). You might also consider one of the ODBC variants, [`RODBC`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html) or [`odbc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for the package names! Unfortunately, I do not see in the documentation how to create a DSN; it looks like both packages want you to already know what the DSN is. Is there a way to create a DSN, as I have in the code posted in my question?

Comment: DSN creation will be totally separate from the R package itself. Some of thise packages however deacribe how to set up a dsn in their documentation.

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/reference/connection-strings#oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ROracle equivalent of Python cx_Oracle's:

```
my_dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("host",port,sid="sid")
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user="user", password="password", dsn=my_dsn)
```

is:

```
connect.string <- paste(
  "(DESCRIPTION=",
  "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=", host, ")(PORT=", port, "))",
  "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=", sid, ")))", sep = "")
con <- dbConnect(drv, username = "user", password = "password", 
                 dbname = connect.string)
```

You can use any of Oracle's standard (non JDBC) connection strings.  One reference is https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionstrings

Comment: Though he was asking whether it was possible to perform a query like `querystring` of Python. Do you confirm that this is **not** possible in `ROracle`? Thank you